# QGIS 3 labelling issue

Tags: qgis, shapefile, labeling

I have added labels showing the District names of Lesotho, but the highlighted feature is not showing a label until I zoom in or out.

Zoom to country extent and label is missing:

[image]

The label shows when zoomed in:

[image]

"**Show all labels for this layer**" has been checked.

Is this a bug with version 3? I am currently using 3.0.3

Comment: You could to use "Map units" for size of labels

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me the same outcome. It will even show me the label if I zoom out, just not when zoomed to the layer extent

Comment: Did you try any of the suggestions in these related links?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286100/why-does-a-single-features-label-not-show?rq=1 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285723/labels-not-rendering-at-appropriate-resolution-for-a-single-polygon-across-diffe

Comment: Yes I tried those solutions (removing holes and checking geometry) but no luck. This is actually the second time I have encountered this issue, and the first time was recently when I had created my own simple polygon with 3 features that had to be labelled. One area wouldn't show a label when zoomed to the layer's extent, but the label would show when zooming in or out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under closer inspection of the vector layer, I noticed there were a few occasions where polygon lines were crossing eachother. After manually removing the unnecessary vertices, the missing label now correctly shows at all zoom levels.